# soap::lite and make use of a squid proxy op port 3128

Tags: perl, soap, proxy

i do have a question.

I'm using the SOAP::Lite module now for some time and it's great

I'm using the script below to setup a session, this is working fine.
(addresses are fake)

```
#! perl -w
use SOAP::Lite;
use Net::SSL;

use warnings;
use strict;

$ENV{'PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME'} = 0;

my $s = SOAP::Lite -> service('https://some.address.com:443/session-api?wsdl') 
-> ns('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'soapenv');

my $session = $s -> startSession(SOAP::Data -> name("arg0") -> value("user"), 
SOAP::Data -> name("arg1") -> value("pwd"));

print "$session\n";
```

But due to changes in the infrastructure i now have to use a squid proxy at 10.10.10.10:3128. The proxy can be used without authentication.

I've been trying to do a lot of options with proxy settings within the soap calls, but none do provide me with the call being done via the proxy, it's always trying to go directly to the server.

Please could you help me in changing the above script in such a way thet he squid proxy is being used.

Thx in advance for your response

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source for WWW::Sales force, there is a proxy option that you might be able to copy here to do what you need.

Comment: Thx for the response. But my experience with this coding isn't that big. Could you provide what should be changed on my example to get it working via the intermediate squid server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant portion from WWW::Salesforce which redhotpenguin referred:

```
my $client =
  SOAP::Lite->readable($readable)
  ->deserializer( WWW::Salesforce::Deserializer->new )
  ->serializer( WWW::Salesforce::Serializer->new )
  ->on_action( sub { return '""' } )->uri($SF_URI)->multirefinplace(1);

if($WEB_PROXY) {
    $client->proxy( $self->{'sf_serverurl'}, proxy => ['https' => $WEB_PROXY ] );
} else {
    $client->proxy( $self->{'sf_serverurl'} );
}
```